# How to avoid roaming question on dual-sim calls?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, dual-sim, roaming

I have a mobile phone with a dual-sim slot and I inserted a SIM in each of them.One of the SIMs get logged in in national roaming which is ok as there is a cooperation between my native service provider and the "foreign" one.
I use a separate app (Roaming Control) to handle roaming correctly.

If now I am logged in in the foreign net and I call out to anybody I get a message, to confirm using roaming and not the secondary SIM which is in its native net:

> Roaming warning
>
> The SIM card that you are about to use is now in roaming. Would you like to continue?

I have to confirm manually which is no problem as long as I have the phone in my hands.

If I am sitting in my car and I use a voice dialer this is nasty: The call does wait for the entry of my decision but does not show the question as the display is in general turned off beforehand. Thus I have to wait for the ring tone and if it is not coming I have to take the phone in my hands (!) and confirm the roaming.

Is there a way to disable this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Android 4.2.1, I have to set **Settings → SIM Management → Roaming → Show roaming reminder → Never**.

Alternatively, use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to disable the notification for a particular SIM.

Setup ADB in PC, [enable USB debugging](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-debugging/info) in device, connect the device into PC, launch a shell on latter and follow these instructions:

To enable data roaming for default SIM, enter:

```
adb shell settings put global data_roaming 1
```

Changes would take effect immediately. For SIM2, change the key to `data_roaming_2`.

If you want to know the details about this command, enter `adb shell settings`. You would easily come to know what the aforesaid command would do.